# what is the LINQ statement to parse a byte array property of a list and copy the result in another list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an AObject and a BObject that are defined like below

```
public class AObject {
     public byte[] Types;
     public string FirstProp;
     public string SecondProp;
}
 
 public class BObject {
     public int Type;
     public string FirstProp;
     public string SecondProp;
}
```

and now i have a list of AObject that i need to copy in BObject but Types property of AObject  should be distribute in BObject List;

Its a simple sample of the list values:

```
 AObjects= { new AObject(){ Types= 1010, first="first" ,second="second" }};
```

and BOject list should contains these for rows:

> BObjects :
>
> (1 , "first" , "second")
>
> (0 , "first" , "second")
>
> (1 , "first" , "second")
>
> (0 , "first" , "second")

I was wondering what's the best linq query to achieve that?

Comment: Since `AObjects= {"1010"' , "first" , "second"}` is absolutely no valid syntax it's not clear what you want to achive. Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg  yes it was a prototype or st . ill change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var BObjects = AObjects.SelectMany(a => a.Types.Select(t => new BObject
{
    Type = t,
    FirstProp = a.FirstProp,
    SecondProp = a.SecondProp
}));
```

Here for each value in `AObject.Types` array new instance of `BOject` is created. `FirstProp` and `SecondProp` are justed copied from `AObject` and `Type` is filled with current byte value from `AObject.Types`.

Comment: we have a list of AObject , i didnt want use foreach on each of them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Enumerable.SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) to solve your problem. Let's say you have an enumerable of `AObject`s like

```
List<AObject> aObjects = new List<AObject>()
{
    new AObject()
    {
        Types = new byte[] { 1, 0, 1, 0 },
        FirstProp = "first1",
        SecondProp = "second1" },
    new AObject()
    {
        Types = new byte[] { 0, 1, 0, 1 },
        FirstProp = "first2",
        SecondProp = "second2"
    },
    //...
};
```

Now you are able to generate an enumerable of `BObject`s by iterating all bytes of each `AObject` like

```
IEnumerable<BObject> bObjects = aObjects.SelectMany(
    a => a.Types.Select(
        b => new BObject()
        {
            Type = b,
            FirstProp = a.FirstProp,
            SecondProp = a.SecondProp
        }));
```

The result (in this case) contains the 8 items like required:

```
{ 1, "first1", "second1" }
{ 0, "first1", "second1" }
{ 1, "first1", "second1" }
{ 0, "first1", "second1" }
{ 0, "first2", "second2" }
{ 1, "first2", "second2" }
{ 0, "first2", "second2" }
{ 1, "first2", "second2" }
```